# Restore damage HDD with "live CD" Photorec

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive

I have dropped my laptop accidentally. Its OS is Windows. So I try to learn how to restore the data.
I took its damaged hdd(1), and connect it to my computer which has a normal hdd(2) with Win7, and external hdd(3) with no OS (simply NTFS hdd).
Then, when I tried to start my computer, it's been stuck (because of the damaged hdd(1)).

I burned the "Ultimate Boot CD", which contain the program "Photorec". I define in BIOS to start the computer with CD, so the CD is starting firstly.

When Photorec is start (on "Ultimate Boot CD"), a Linux OS is loaded to RAM and under this OS the Photorec is working. I execute all the levels according to the Photorec "step-by-step" guide. I defined the external hdd(3) to be the place the whole data will be restored to. and it's work - I can see the images from the damaged hdd(1).

The problem is comming after that: when turning off the computer and disconnecting the damaged hdd(1) to allow the computer to work as regular, while running my win7, I can't see the restored data and images in the external hdd(3). moreover, when connecting the damaged hdd(1) again and start the "Ultimate Boot CD", I found that the data had gone. seem like never restored anything (I guess it's because the linux was exist on the RAM, not in hdd...)
So, what should I do? how can I get the files (that I saw them under the linux on restoring) in extrnal hdd(3) while operating the win7 and keep it 
forever and not just temporary?

Comment: This seems very unfortunate, @Raviv! :( I highly doubt you'd be able to recover any of your files since the laptop had been dropped. This indicates that the mechanical hard drive has a physical damage which, sadly, you won't be able to fix by yourself. Your best bet at getting any of those files stored on the HDD back is a professional data recovery company. I'd recommend you to find a cost-efficient one ASAP and give that HDD to them. Hopefully, they'd be able to get something off of it. I'd definitely not temper with the drive physically, though. Good luck!

Comment: As I wrote: it's work - I can see the images from the damaged hdd(1), so I success to restore it. The only problem is to save it in way that the windows also can read it...